# Zend_Search_Lucene View entire Cache

Tags: zend-framework, zend-search-lucene

Is it possible to view the entire cache in a laid out clear view of what is indexed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of how you would do this in zend, but if you want to look at the indexes to see what state they are in, then I would recommend a deskapp called [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/)

It's a java app, that you point to where you lucene index is being stored and you can then view what has been indexed, run simple queries and alike.  It's a very useful tool.

Help that helps.